# sendKeyDownUpSync doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, instrumentation, keyevent

I've got some problem with **sendKeyDownUpSync**. I want to use it in my widget to control inbuilt music player. It works almost correctly. Almost because when i call function:

```
public void previousTruck()
    {
        final Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {         
            public void run() { 
                   new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS);

        }).start();     
    }
```

It start changing music from my playlist but lots of time, why?
I want to make only one "step" to next song from play list.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in the *OnCreate*

```
myThread = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
        m_Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS);
    }
};
```

Somewhere in your *previousTruck*

```
myThread.start();
```

**P.S. Be attentive!!** Creating Thread object without the *run()* invoking causes the  memory leak - [see](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7979). It happens during changing of screen orientation if you create a thread object inside the *OnCreate* and there is not the *run()* invoking till the next changing of screen orientation. That is why the best approach is to create Thread object immediately before it's *start()* invoking.